# 2022 Premiere on New Macbook M1 export color looks terrible. How to fix?

Tags: premiere, premiere-pro

I have a huge problem. Editing on new Macbook, latest version of Premiere. Color looks awesome in Premiere, on export, it is unwatchable.

[image]

I tried applying the Gamma Correction LUT and it helped one or two notches but still unwatchable.
I don't know what to do.
I have disabled True Tone and this happens each time I export.

[image]

Watched the video on other devices, and the color is still terrible. 
How can I fix this?

Update:

Turned on Color Management. So now the timeline and export look equally bad.

Switched Display to HDR Video which is P3. Still export looks terrible.